# Finding best matching bitmap from a set

Tags: algorithm, bitmap, pattern-matching, comparison

I have a set A of small bitmaps of similar dimenstions, let's say 8x8. One bit per position. The set consists of a couple of hundred such bitmaps.

Next I have a never-ending stream of millions of bitmaps... and for each one of them I need to find the bitmap from set A that matches the best. I will probably not find a perfect match. A good match is the one that LOOKS similar, as a picture. Ie a bitmap with all the "leftmost" bits set is a poor match for one with all the rightmost bits set. The same number of bits are set, but their position must be taken into consideration as well. A bitmap that is shifted one step to the right has no bits that matches exactly, but it will look very similar to the original, so that would be a pretty good match. Shift it some more and it will not match so great anymore.

Soo... it can be an approximation, it can be fuzzy. Speed is preferred over perfection. I looked into the SSIM index algorithm that measures similarity between images but I think it's overkill and I probably need something more specialized.

If I can do some precalculation and then just use some sort of lookup-tables that would be great for performance, but I'm not sure how I'd do that. Hashing won't be of much use in this case...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The straight similarity measure between two binary images is their Hamming distance (i.e. every pair of corresponding pixels gets the same weight). This implicitly takes into account their geometric placement, but doesn't cope with shifts.

To handle shifts, I guess that you cannot really avoid shifting explicitly then comparing. If you limit yourself to shifts by ±1, this implies a total of 9 comparisons instead of 1. Dealing with rotations or scalings seems costly/meaningless for such tiny images.

To speed-up the search, you can think of a coarse-to-fine approach: form reduced images by adding the pixels in 2x2 blocks, to get 4x4, then 2x2 and even 1x1 reductions. These thumnails won't be binary anymore, but the total number of bits goes decreasing. Identical images will have identical reductions, and similar or shifted images will have similar reductions.

Now you can organize the image database as a tree such that every full resolution image points to its reduction, and so on recursively. Then to match a given image, form the 1x1 thumbnail, select the closest matche(s) in the database and continue with the descendants while progressively increasing the reduction.

Comment: The reductions you mention, I think I was toying with something similar in mind but you explained it better with words. I am going to try this. I will start by thinking it over some more and draw up the logic in pseudo-code. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeOrElse: wish you success.